# Do I need quotes around the full path when using a variable?

Tags: shell, sh

I have a variable `CONF_DIR` which denotes the configuration directory. In this directory, there is a file `essentials.conf`. I want to add configuration parameters to this file.

This `CONF_DIR` can denote a directory which contains spaces, or any other special symbols.

Is it enough to write the following?

```
echo enable_logging=true >> "$CONF_DIR"/essentials.conf
```

Or do I need to enclose the full path with `"`?

```
echo enable_logging=true >> "$CONF_DIR/essentials.conf"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the POSIX standard, [double quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html) "preserves the literal value of all characters within the quotes, with the exception of `$`, `` ` ``, `\`".

Here, you want to expand `$CONF_DIR` and preserve the literal value of the spaces within. No need to preserve `/essentials.conf` which doesn't contain any expandable character. So you can carry on with what you wrote.

Answer (score -1):

You dont need Quotes at all.

You can just run things like:

```
nano $CONF_DIR/essentials.conf
```

It would work.

But may you ask such questions in Linux/Unix section of StackExchange.

Comment: Mmh, I wouldn't say that. `echo test > dir_with space/test.txt` won't work.

Comment: Acutally on FreeBSD not working at all ... ok may dependent on OS

Comment: Have a peek on the [FreeBSD sh manual page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sh&sektion=&n=1): "Enclosing characters within double quotes preserves the literal meaning of all characters **except dollar sign** (`$`), [...]".

Comment: Using the normal /bin/sh ... in my BSD version (Of couse its old) it results in a string with output "$PATH" at echo

Comment: Ok, very strange. I haven't found a link related to what you experienced.

Comment: @SandroSchaurer That's very much *not* the "normal" `/bin/sh` then.

Comment: Yep, maybe a little `ls -l /bin/sh` could be show what's behind this `sh`.